# Регулярное выражение в Perl

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Есть значит текст. Надо убрать оттуда все `</p> и <p>`. Текст хранится в скаляре, и записывается построчно конкатенацией. Но почему-то, после строки `"<p> </p>"` в тексте регулярное выражение не находит эти теги. Использую такое рег. выр.:

```
s/< p>|<\/p>//g
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ладно, другой вопрос, как описать регулярным выражением всё то что находится в скобках < > ??? почему не подходит <.+> ?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема может быть и в лишнем пробеле. В вашем случае, когда надо убрать только тэги `<p>` и `</p>`, можно выражение записать проще:

```
s!</?p>!!g
```

Вместо восклицательного знака можете использовать другой разделитель либо скобки (не только фигурные):

```
s{</?p>}{}g
```

P. S. `man perlre`

**добавка/22:25:** `s/<.+>//` вам не подойдёт потому, что `+` сам по себе (без идущего после него `?`) — *жадный* (greedy) квантификатор и в таком виде выражение `s/<.+>//` означает «знак „меньше“, после которого идёт как можно бóльшее количество символов (включая знаки „больше“ и „меньше“), а затем — знак „больше“».

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтоб убрать все тэги, используйте `s/<.+?>//g`